# Union, intersection and difference of 2 sets,using just string functions

Tags: c

I have the following program that finds out the reunion, the intersection and the difference between the sets consisting of 2 strings. In my functions, I treat strings as one-dimensional arrays. I need a program that does the same thing, but that uses the maximum possible string processing functions. I'd be very glad if you could help me, I'm still a beginner. Here's my code below :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


void stringToSet(char str[])
{
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i  < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < strlen(str); j++)
        {
            if (str[j] == str[i])
            {
                for (k = j; str[k]; k++)
                {
                    str[k] = str[k + 1];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\nThe set is : %s\n", str);
}
void findUnion( char *str1, char *str2)
{
    int counter = 0;
    char str3[100];

    while (str1[counter])
    {
        str3[counter] = str1[counter];
        counter++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str2); i++)
    {
        int flag = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(str1); j++)
        {
            if (str2[i] == str1[j])
            {
                flag = 1;
            }

        }

        if (flag == 0)
        {
            str3[counter] = str2[i];
            counter++;
        }
    }
    str3[counter] = '\0';
    printf("\nUnion : ");
    (*str3) ? printf("%s", str3): printf("\n Empty set!");
}

void findIntersection(const char *str1, const char *str2)
{
    int k = 0;
    char str3[100];

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str1); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(str2); j++)
        {
            if (str1[i] == str2[j])
            {
                str3[k] = str1[i];
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
    str3[k] = '\0';
    printf("\nIntersection : ");
    (*str3) ? printf("%s", str3): printf("\n Empty set!");
}
void findDifferention(const char *str1, const char *str2)
{
    char str3[100];

    int  l = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str1); i++)
    {
        int flag = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(str2); j++)
        {
            if (str1[i] == str2[j])
                flag = 1;
        }
        if (flag == 0)
        {
            str3[l] = str1[i];
            l++;
        }
    }

    str3[l] = '\0';
    printf("\nDiference :");
    (*str3) ? printf("%s", str3): printf("\n Empty set!");

}
int main()
{

    char str1[100];
    char str2[100];

    printf("String 1 :");
    fgets(str1,sizeof  str1, stdin);
    stringToSet(str1);

    printf("String  2 :");
    fgets(str2,sizeof  str2, stdin);
    stringToSet(str2);

    findUnion(str1, str2);
    findIntersection(str1, str2);
    findDifferention(str1, str2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `stringToSet` function would benefit from actually sorting the string (_e.g._ with `qsort`).  Then you can perform a O(N) pass to eliminate duplicates.  Now, all your set operations become trivial.

Comment: You want to optimise code?   Except for validating characters for `sets` & better algorithm functions I don't see much use for string functions here.

Comment: @SparKot I should use functions to compare, copy, and so on, from the string.h. i do not necessarily need an optimization

Comment: @SparKot For example, this : `while (str1[counter]){str3[counter] = str1[counter]; counter++;}` can be replaced by this `while (str1[counter]) { strcpy(str3,str1);counter++; }`;

Comment: There really isn't any point using string functions.  They are not designed to treat strings as sets.  As mentioned above, that basically leaves only trivial stuff like copying and direct comparison.  The more practical thing you can do is improve your implementation.  Here is what I was suggesting: https://godbolt.org/z/s3qaMKcsd